# How to reload iCarousel when returning from segued View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, icarousel

I have an iCarousel control embedded into a View. Each iCarousel "tile" (or item) can be tapped to show a modal form sheet which contains editable data which is saved to a DB with Core Data.

Once I make changes by pressing a "Save" button, and the view is dismissed, I would like to reload the iCarousel specific item to refresh the data in the tile that was tapped.

Where can I put that code? (I put NSLogs in every event but nothing is triggered when returning from a segue.

Also, I tried using an Unwind Segue (I am targeting iOS 6.1), but if I tie my Save button to the Unwind IBAction, then the Save method I have on the View loaded via Segue is completely ignored.

Comment: Please provide some more details of your implementation, or code etc

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)reloadData;
```

This reloads all carousel views from the dataSource and refreshes the carousel display.

[Check Link For carousel methods](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: Thanks, but I was already aware of the existence of that method, I should have titled my question "where" to place the reload method.

Comment: You will try to placed in the viewWillAppear Method to reload the icarousel Method

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using delegates to keep track of whether or not something changed, and when something did change, I modified a BOOL property that I check upon UnwindSegue and then I reload the Carousel in there.